# PHP while(true) loop for file updates

Tags: php, while-loop

I've got the following problem at hand:

I'm having users on two seperate pages, but saving page input to the same text file. While one user is editing, the other can't. I'm keeping track of this with sessions and writing changes and who's turn to edit it is in a file.

Works fine so far, the output in the end is quite similar to a chat. However, right now I'm having users manually actualize their page and reload the file. What I'd like to do is have the page execute a redirect when the file-timestamp changes (to indicate that the last user has saved their edits and its another users turn). I've looked into javascript shortpolling a little, but then found the php filmtime function and it looks much easier to use. Well - here's what I got:

```
while(true){
   $oldtimestamp=filemtime(msks/$session['user']['kampfnr'].txt);
   $waittimer=2;
   $waittimer++;
   sleep($waittimer);
   $newtimestamp=filemtime(msks/$session['user']['kampfnr'].txt);

   if ($eintragszeit2 > $eintragszeit1){
       addnav("","kampf_ms.php?op=akt");
       redirect("kampf_ms.php?op=akt");
   }}
```

In theory, while the user sees the output "it's ... turn to edit the file." this should loop in the background, checking if the file has already been updated, and if yes, redirect the user.

Practically this heavily affects server perfomance (I'm on shared hosting) until it breaks with a memory exceeded error message.

Is something wrong with the code? Or is it generally a bad idea to use a while loop in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP language should be only used to generate web content (client do a request to the server => server calls the required script, and returns the response to the client).
Once page is loaded and displayed to the client, the connection is closed, so Internet can die, the client isn't informed...

So with an infinite loop, not only the client can wait for response... an infinite time, but also the server may be heavy impacted because of load... Effectively It is a really bad idea :)

PHP can't be used to make a bidirectional communication: **it is just called to build web pages that client demands, and so he can't do anything "in the background"** (not directly, effectively you can call an external script, but not for notify a client...)

Also, to do a bidirectional communication, php and "regular" http is not good, because of client / server architecture (the server only answers client request, it is passive)

I can suggest to use WebSocket protocol, to do a chat application:

> http://socket.io/
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

But for that, you need to use an "active" server solution, such as node.js or ruby (depends of your server capabilities...)

The other way if you want to stay in php is that client makes Ajax request every 10 seconds, for example, to call a php script which check the file, and send back a message to the client if file is updated, **but it is really deprecated**, because of heavy performance loss, so forget it immediately.